# Usage of "indeed"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Can we use the word `indeed` in middle of sentences like:

> 1. I am **indeed** very grateful.
> 2. It is **indeed** very unfortunate.

And I'd also like to know what are the other ways in which we can use the word `indeed`.

Comment: Take a look at the example sentences [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/indeed?q=indeed). “It is indeed a remarkable achievement,” from the linked website fits the same pattern your sentences do.

Comment: Yes, these sentences are correct. *Indeed* is functioning as an adverb.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your sentences are correct:

I am indeed very grateful.
It is indeed very unfortunate.

"Indeed" is used the same as the word "definitely."  Another use is:

A: Want some more pie?
B: Indeed I do!

Comment: It is devoutly to be hoped that, in your capacity as a teacher of ESL, you do not teach your students to spell the word _definAtely._ (Since corrected by another reader.) From there, it is a short and deadly drop to _defiantly._

Answer (score 0):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.bcu.ac.uk/view/Entry/94220?rskey=jIpeRq&result=3#eid) tells us that *indeed* was two words - *in deed* - until the 17th century, with *deed* being an action, either physical or legal. Hence, in a similar way to *actually*, *indeed* emphasises by indicating that something is as real as a deed or act, and not just empty words.